# NSData comparison in test case

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata

**Overview:**

There is a function `f1` that returns `NSData`.

Is there a way I can write a test case to test a function that returns `NSData` ?

How do I create the variable `expectedOutput` (refer code below) ?

**Example:**

```
@interface Car : NSObject

- (NSData*) f1;

@end

@implementation Car

- (NSData*) f1 {

    NSData *someData = [[NSData alloc] init]; //This is just an example, the real code has some logic to build the NSData

    return someData;
}

@end
```

**Test Case:**

```
- (void) test {
    Car *c1;

    NSData *actualOutput = [c1 f1];
    NSData *expectedOutput = ??? //How can I build this NSData ?

    XCTAssertEqualObjects(actualOutput, expectedOutput);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Steps**

1. Write `expectedOutput` (`NSData`) to file (one time)
2. In the test case read the file and populate `expectedOutput`
3. Compare `expectedOutput` to `actualOutput`

**Step 1:**

```
    - (void) writeExpectedDataToFile {}

        //Write expected data to file (to be done only once)
        NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"expected.txt"]];

        [data writeToFile:databasePath atomically:YES];
    }
```

**Step 2:**

```
    - (void) test {
        Car *c1;

        NSData *actualOutput = [c1 f1];

        //Reading from file
        NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
        NSURL* fileName1 = [bundle URLForResource:@"expected" withExtension:@"txt"];
        NSData *expectedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[fileName1.path stringByExpandingTildeInPath]];

        XCTAssertEqualObjects(actualOutput, expectedOutput);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Method of building of expectedOutput depend on contents of the NSData. It should based on meaning of f1.
If you do not know that type of data should generate f1, you can check length and class of a returned NSData (If you know length in bytes).
If you know, that f1 encode some string to data, you can generate a  destination string and compare the generated string with string created from the returned data.
If you know, sequence of bytes that should generate this function (for example you have same function on other language, or have a etalon bytes), you can load the bytes to NSData from disc and compare it with actualOutput.